# Invalid columns names Insert statement

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to create add button in the gridview. I have 3 joining tables and 3 drop-down lists.

That is the error that I get:

> Additional information: Invalid column name 'Quotation_Number'. Invalid column name 'Customer_Name'. Invalid column name 'Machine_Model'.

Can you help me? I think the problem is in the insert statement

Thanks

```
public void userSales()
{
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SalesActivity.Activity_ID, SalesActivity.Date, SalesActivity.Quatation_Number, CUSTOMER.Customer_Name, PRODUCTS.Machine_Model, SalesActivity.Quantity, SalesActivity.valueGBR, SalesActivity.valueEUR, SalesActivity.Rate, SalesActivity.weightedValue, STATUS.Status, SalesActivity.estDecisionDate, SalesActivity.PromisedDeliveryDate FROM SalesActivity INNER JOIN CUSTOMER ON SalesActivity.Customer_ID = CUSTOMER.Customer_ID INNER JOIN PRODUCTS ON SalesActivity.Product_ID = PRODUCTS.Product_ID INNER JOIN STATUS ON SalesActivity.Status_ID = STATUS.Status_ID ", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();

    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ds.Tables[0].NewRow());  // if record not found then returning a blank table structure
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        int columncount = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count;

        GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
        GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
        GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = columncount;
        GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No Records Found";
    }
}

protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex; //this open new index that is edit mode
    userSales();
}

protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;   //after cancel button want go to one index back that's y -1
    userSales();
}

protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName.Equals("AddNew"))
    {
        TextBox txtActivity = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ftxtActivity");
        TextBox ftxtDate = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ftxtDate");
        TextBox ftxtQno = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ftxtQno");
        DropDownList fddlCName = GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("fddlCName") as DropDownList;
        DropDownList fddlMmodel = GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("fddlMmodel") as DropDownList;
        TextBox ftxtQuantity = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ftxtQuantity");
        TextBox ftxtvalueGBR = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ftxtvalueGBR");
        TextBox ftxtvalueEUR = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ftxtvalueEUR");
        TextBox ftxtRate = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ftxtRate");
        TextBox ftxtweightedValue = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ftxtweightedValue");
        DropDownList fddlStatus = GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("fddlStatus") as DropDownList;
        TextBox ftxtestDecisionDate = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ftxtestDecisionDate");
        TextBox ftxtPromisedDeliveryDate = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ftxtPromisedDeliveryDate");

        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO SalesActivity(Activity_ID, Date, Quotation_Number, Customer_Name, Machine_Model,Quantity, valueGBR, valueEUR, Rate, weightedValue, Status, estDecisionDate, PromisedDeliveryDate) VALUES(@Activity_ID, @Date, @Quotation_Number, @Customer_Name, @Machine_Model, @Quantity, @valueGBR, @valueEUR, @Rate, @weightedValue, @Status, @estDecisionDate, @PromisedDeliveryDate)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Activity_ID", txtActivity.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", ftxtDate.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quotation_Number", ftxtQno.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Customer_Name", fddlCName.SelectedItem.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Machine_Model", fddlMmodel.SelectedItem.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity",  ftxtQuantity.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valueGBR", ftxtvalueGBR.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valueEUR",  ftxtvalueEUR.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@weightedValue",ftxtweightedValue.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rate",  ftxtRate.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status",  fddlStatus.SelectedItem.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estDecisionDate", ftxtestDecisionDate.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PromisedDeliveryDate", ftxtPromisedDeliveryDate.Text.Trim());

        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();

        if (result == 1)
        {
            userSales();
            Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('" + txtActivity.Text + "'+'Sale Details inserted successfully');</script>");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('" + txtActivity.Text + "'+' Sale Details not inserted');</script>");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: above is a select statement not insert

Comment: What have you done to investigate the error yourself? Have you ascertained that the table `SalesActivity` contains these columns?

Comment: hi the insert is under the select

Comment: Hi yes salesactivity table have Quatation_Number and the other 3 is dropdown lists from the other 3 tables. Customer name is the dropdwonlist from customer table  which i inner join in the select statement

Comment: and the other two the are dropdown lists from the other tables too

Comment: Please handle `IDisposable`s correctly.

Comment: `Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert(...` so many things wrong in one line of code.

Answer (score 1):

Your Select Statement is executing this...

```
SELECT SalesActivity.Activity_ID
    ,SalesActivity.DATE
    ,SalesActivity.Quatation_Number
    ,CUSTOMER.Customer_Name
    ,PRODUCTS.Machine_Model
    ,SalesActivity.Quantity
    ,SalesActivity.valueGBR
    ,SalesActivity.valueEUR
    ,SalesActivity.Rate
    ,SalesActivity.weightedValue
    ,STATUS.STATUS
    ,SalesActivity.estDecisionDate
    ,SalesActivity.PromisedDeliveryDate
FROM SalesActivity
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER ON SalesActivity.Customer_ID = CUSTOMER.Customer_ID
INNER JOIN PRODUCTS ON SalesActivity.Product_ID = PRODUCTS.Product_ID
INNER JOIN STATUS ON SalesActivity.Status_ID = STATUS.Status_ID
```

Machine_Model and Customer_Name do not belong to SalesActivity Table, they belong to Products and Customer respectively. And your issue with Quotation_Number is Quatation_Number in the select.

change this...

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO SalesActivity(Activity_ID, Date, Quotation_Number, Customer_Name, Machine_Model,Quantity, valueGBR, valueEUR, Rate, weightedValue, Status, estDecisionDate, PromisedDeliveryDate) VALUES(@Activity_ID, @Date, @Quotation_Number, @Customer_Name, @Machine_Model, @Quantity, @valueGBR, @valueEUR, @Rate, @weightedValue, @Status, @estDecisionDate, @PromisedDeliveryDate)", con);
```

to this...

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO SalesActivity(Activity_ID, Date, Quatation_Number,Quantity, valueGBR, valueEUR, Rate, weightedValue, estDecisionDate, PromisedDeliveryDate) VALUES(@Activity_ID, @Date, @Quotation_Number, @Quantity, @valueGBR, @valueEUR, @Rate, @weightedValue, @estDecisionDate, @PromisedDeliveryDate)", con);
```

and remove the following lines...

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Customer_Name", fddlCName.SelectedItem.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Machine_Model", fddlMmodel.SelectedItem.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status",  fddlStatus.SelectedItem.Text);
```

The insert should now work.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer  yes they do not belong but for this i inner join their tables so i can display them ? Do you know how to fix it ?

Comment: Please if you can help me i just need really to finish it

Comment: Georgi Georgiev, I updated my answer with the required changes.

Comment: Hi is not working like this as well. i need to find the way how to insert this dropdown lists only that is left :(

Comment: What error are you getting now or what is not working? The fields you are referring to come from different tables. You'll need to somehow grab the IDs from those dropdown lists so you can include the Customer_ID, Product_ID and Status_ID in the insert statement. I can't tell from you code block how those dropdowns are populated.

Comment: is not inserting the dropdownlists  values